# HTML5/CSS3: How Do I Prevent LI Items From Being Pushed To The Right with No Bullet Without Using JavaScript or PHP?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

For HTML and CSS, how do I prevent `li` items with `list-style: none;` from actually being pushed to the right and just stick it to the edge? My English is not so good, so I'll show some examples.

I searched Google and Google doesn't seem to understand what I mean.

Here is my code snippet and please run it to realize what I mean:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      body {
        border: 1px solid #000;
      }
      ul {
        list-style: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>a
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
      <li>d
        <ul>
          <li>i</li>
          <li>ii</li>
          <li>iii</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** I added a border to show the alignment of the `li`.

Did you see how it became stair-type and it's not sticking to the edge?

My question is how do I make them stick to the edge perfectly aligned into one line like this?

```
a
1
2
3
b
c
d
i
ii
iii
```

If you have any answers, please let me know.

Comment: add this css rule to ul element. padding-left:0; that should fix

Comment: The reason why I'm asking this is because I'm creating a vertical block-style navbar. If I clear padding, I'm ruining my navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw an older answer which said to place `margin-left: -40px` in my code and that was the most helpful solution and it worked!

I asked it for a navbar with padding.

That answer was removed from my post though.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to add 1 line of CSS:

`padding-left: 0;` to remove the padding.

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d
    <ul>
      <li>i</li>
      <li>ii</li>
      <li>iii</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      body {
        border: 1px solid #000;
      }
      ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>a
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
      <li>d
        <ul>
          <li>i</li>
          <li>ii</li>
          <li>iii</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Just clear default margin and padding of ul item.

[image]